# How to get an information from Database(phpmyadmin) with two categories

Tags: database

I want to fetch some data that with the same "id" and "category" here's my code:

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id_no'$id'`

I want to add like where `category = 'product'`. What should I add between  `id_no = $id'` and `category = 'product'`

Hope you can help me. Thankyou.

Comment: Need more info about your schema

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ? On the `WHERE` clause ?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE id_no = '$id' AND category = 'product'
```

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp),

- The AND operator displays a record if both the first condition AND the second condition are true.
- The OR operator displays a record if either the first condition OR the second condition is true.